# Envio de datos JSONObject

Tags: android, json, jsonobject

Tengo un problema con mi código de Android Studio. Mi aplicación debe de enviar una información que va recolectando pero no se como estructurarlo  ya que el cuerpo del envió es largo alguien me podría decir, lo he intentado enviarlo con varios JSONObject pero no he tenido éxito espero que me puedan ayudar.

```
 HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("WSUser", "Tums4.WS".toCharArray());
                    }
                });
```

dejo la estructura del cuerpo:

```
{
  "Equipo": {
    "EquipoMotriz": "test",
    "Viajes": {
      "NoViaje": "test",
      "Repartos": {
        "Reparto": {
          "Pedido": "test",
          "CartaPorte": "test",
          "CargaFecIniR": "test",
          "CargaHorIniR": "test",
          "CargaFecFinR": "test",
          "CargaHorFinR": "test",
          "DescFecIniR": "test",
          "DescHorIniR": "test",
          "DescFecFinR": "test",
          "DescHorFinR": "test",
          "LlegaCteFecR": "test",
          "LlegaCteHorR": "test",
          "SalidCteFecR": "test",
          "SalidCteHorR": "test",
          "LlegaCteDesFecR": "test",
          "LlegaCteDesHorR": "test",
          "SalidCteDesFecR": "test",
          "SalidCteDesHorR": "test",
          "Paradas": {
            "Parada": {
              "NUM_VIAJE": "test",
              "PEDIDO": "test",
              "ENTREGA": "test",
              "CVE_PAR": "test",
              "CLA_PAR": "test",
              "TIP_PAR": "test",
              "LATITUD": "test",
              "LONGITUD": "test",
              "FECHA_C": "test",
              "HORA_C": "test"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al  sitio: ¿Deseas enviar esto a una petición? ¿Como enviaría estos datos, podrias agregarlo?. Revisa por favor [ask], no olvides realizar el [tour], del sitio.

Comment: Es enviarlo a una petición

Comment: ¿Pero que tipo  GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, ETC...? esta información debes definirla en tu pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracia ya lo puse es post